# Using the word "again" as a clause in a question

Tags: commas

If I end a sentence with the word *again*, I do not usually need a comma such as in the following example:

"Here we go again."

However, I have been unable to find information about using the word again as part of a question. Should I be using a comma in the following question or not?

"What is the definition of irony, again?"

Is the word *again* considered a dependent clause or something else?

Comment: In your example, "again" modifies an understood verb phrase, "give the definition of irony".   The fact that something is left implicit doesn't change the part of speech.

Answer (score 2):

In the two examples you provide, the adverb "again" servers two different functions.

In "here we go again" it is modifying the verb "go". There should not be a comma between a verb and its adverb, regardless of whether it's at the end of the sentence or not. Here are some more examples:

> Please come **again**.
>
> I will do it **again**.
>
> Trying **again** was not a good idea.

In "What is the definition of irony, again?", the word again is modifying the independent clause "what is the definition of irony". It is making a conceptual connection between this sentence and a previous one. **It's not a separate clause, but a type of conjunction (a conjunctive adverb).** It needs to be preceded or offset by commas, regardless of where it is in the sentence. Here are more examples:

> **Again,** the definition of irony is [...].
>
> Why is **it, again,** that you're looking up this word?